# Compute $df_1: ST_1^3 \rightarrow TSO(3)_I$

Tags: general-topology

In short, the problem is to compute $df_1: T_1S^3 \rightarrow T_{I}SO(3)$, given $f: S^3 \rightarrow SO(3), r \in S^3, f(r) \in SO(3): f(r)(q) = rqr^{-1}, q\in R^3$. I just get to study differential topology, so I have no clue how to do the computation of df. Thank you very much!

More detials:

$SO(3)$ denotes the *special orthogonal group*, which is the (open) subset of $O(3)$ on which the determinant is one.

I have shown that every element of $SO(3)$ fixes a line in $\mathbb{R}$ pointwise and then $SO(3)$ is connected.

Also, suppose $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a smooth map of Lie groups such that $f(g_1g_2) = f(g_1)f(g_2)$ for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$ (this is called a Lie group homomorphism). Then I proved that the derivative $df_g$ has constant rank.

I am stuck at the question: Consider the map $f: S^3 \rightarrow SO(3)$ given by $r \in S^3$ maps to the element $f(r) \in SO(3)$ such that $f(r)(q) = rqr^{-1}$ for $q \in \mathbb{R}$, thought of as a purely imaginary quaternion. Show that this is a Lie group homomorphism, and compute $df_1: TS^3_1 \rightarrow TSO(3)_I$.

I am given then *Hint:* $TS^3_1$ is identified with the purely imaginary quaternions as it sits in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $TSO(3)_I$ is identified with the skew-symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices as it sits in $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$.

More specifically, I am confused with these questions:

1, What is the explicit form of $r^{-1}$? I used $r^*/\|r\|^2$, where $r^* = a -bi-cj-dk$. But then it becomes cumbersome during the computation.

2, I am aware of that quaternions are not really 4-dim since it is bounded on the unit sphere. So should it be 9 x 3 matrix other than 4 x 9? Also, f is 9 dimensional, so df should be 9 columns, right?

Comment: You might want to use that $\exp_I \circ df_1 = f \circ \exp_1$.

Comment: Newbie question: what is $r^{-1}$ for $r\in S^3$?

Comment: @WillNelson $S^3$ is the set of unit quaternions.

Comment: A computation that will come in handy in differential geometry and in working with Lie groups is this: If $g\colon U\to G$ is a smooth map from an open set $U\subset\mathbb R^k$ to a Lie group, what is $d(g^{-1})$? (Hint: Differentiate $gg^{-1}=\text{constant}$.)

Comment: @AlexanderThumm Thank you Alex!

Comment: @WillNelson $r^{-1} = r^*/\|r\|^2$ - thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, thank you so much for your help! I got $d{gg^{-1}} = dg g^{-1} + g dg^{-1} = 0$. Could you give me some further directions? I only learned differential geometry on curves and surfaces, and no Lie Groups at all. So I am get really stuck here. Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't be scared of Lie groups. Just think of matrices. So your equation says that $d(g^{-1}) = -(g^{-1})(dg)(g^{-1})$. Try this out to prove that $T_ISO(3)=\{A\in M_{3\times 3}: A^T = -A\}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you Ted. Sorry I am really slow here - could you explain that how $g$ related to this question? And how to drive forward from here? Thank you so much!

Comment: $O(3)$ is given by $g^Tg=I$. Differentiate.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks so much! So now I get:

Differentiating $g^Tg = I$ obtain $d(g^T)g + g^T dg = I$.

Then I get lost here, since $dI = I$ rather than 0. Or this is not true?

Comment: This is a common confusion. $I$ is a constant matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I got it. So it actually is $d I(x) = I(x)$. But here we are just differentiate I, so get 0.

Comment: So now I got d(g^T)=−(g^T)(dg)(g^T) - what should I do next? Thanks~! @TedShifrin